# Return Range Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

```
def myRange
  this_range = [0..3]
  return this_range
end

puts myRange
puts rand(myRange)
```

> ```
> Mac:Postazure$ ruby TESTER.rb
> 0..3
> TESTER.rb:7:in `rand': no implicit conversion of Array into Integer (TypeError)
>     from TESTER.rb:7:in `<main>'
> ```

This returns a Range of '0..3' but it can't be used as above. Any ideas how I might get that to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[0..3]` doesn't return a `Range`. It returns an `Array` with one Range element.

```
2.1.1 :001 > [0..3].class
 => Array
```

To return a Range, change the code to

```
def myRange
  this_range = 0..3
  return this_range
end

myRange.class
 => Range
```

or even better

```
def my_range
  0..3
end
```

Then you can call

```
puts rand(myRange)
```

Coding style notes:

- In Ruby you use implicit return
- In Ruby naming is underscore_case
- No need for a variable there

Comment: +1 for adding the coding-style info. Regurgitating non-idiomatic code with a tweak to make something work is a disservice to newbies, and the community in general. Pointing them in the right direction is always a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you used an array instead of a range.

Try something like this:

```
def myRange
  this_range = 0..3
  return this_range
end

puts myRange
puts rand(myRange)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead `(1..3)` not `[1..3]` and it should work :)

```
def myRange
  this_range = (0..3)
  return this_range
end

puts rand(myRange)
#==> 2
```